# Box API access denied, permission issue when trying to create a folder

Tags: python, django, box-api, rauth

I don't know why it's not letting me create a file at Box. I tried to change the settings around, but I still can't find the solution. Here is the code inside my django's view file:

```
#from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from rauth import OAuth2Service
import json

# Create your views here.
def access_box(request):
    CLIENT_ID = 'xxx'
    CLIENT_SECRET = 'xxx'
    box_storage = OAuth2Service(
                            name='Box',
                            client_id=CLIENT_ID,
                            client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET,
                            authorize_url='https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/authorize',
                            access_token_url='https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/token',
                            base_url='https://www.box.com/'
                            )
    redirect_uri = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/access-box/'

    params = {          
          'redirect_uri': redirect_uri,
          'response_type': 'code',         
          }
    url = box_storage.get_authorize_url(**params)

    if request.GET:        
        if request.GET.get('code'):
            code = request.GET.get('code')   
            data = {'code': code,
                    'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
                    'redirect_uri': redirect_uri,
                    }     

            payload = {
                       'name': 'testfolder',
                       'id': '0',
                       }
            session = box_storage.get_auth_session(data=data, decoder=json.loads)
            r = session.post('https://api.box.com/2.0/folders', params=payload)
            print(r.url)
            print(r.json())
            #r = r.json()
            #html = "<html><body>request available! authentication code: {0}<p>{1}</p></body></html>".format(code, r)
            html = "<html><body>request available! authentication code: {0}</body></html>".format(code)    
            return HttpResponse(html)
        else:
            return HttpResponse("zilch!")
    else:
        html = "<html><body></h1>Allow rushdGYM access to Box.com</h1><p><a href='{0}'>Allow now</a></body></html>".format(url)    
        return HttpResponse(html)
```

This is the **response** I received trying to create a folder @ Box.

```
{u'status': 400, u'code': u'bad_request', u'request_id': u'2143252gdf3', u'context_info': {u'errors': [{u'reason': u'missing_parameter', u'message': u"'parent' is required", u'name': u'parent'}, {u'reason': u'missing_parameter', u'message': u"'name' is required", u'name': u'name'}]}, u'help_url': u'http://developers.box.com/docs/#errors', u'message': u'Bad Request', u'type': u'error'}
```

Any guidelines to steer me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, look at the error message you posted; it clearly states what the errors are:

```
[
    {u'reason': u'missing_parameter', u'message': u"'parent' is required", u'name': u'parent'}, 
    {u'reason': u'missing_parameter', u'message': u"'name' is required", u'name': u'name'}
]
```

So, you'll have to supply `parent` and `name` in your request.

---

Second, note that the Box API expects the payload to be JSON encoded and present in the body.

As of now, you're sending it as a request (GET) parameter, using the `params` argument to `session.post`, you should use the `data` argument instead.

Might also want to set your `Content-Type` header to `application/json`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Thomas O. I used **data** as you suggested, and then encoded my payload to **JSON**, and that worked!

I only had to change this:

```
r = session.post('https://api.box.com/2.0/folders', data=json.dumps(payload))
```

Comment: You should probably change your base url to https://api.box.com.   The auth URLs are www.box.com, but all API calls go to api.box.com